# Name lookup: downsides to using unqualified class name inside a class definition / omitting template parameters?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, explicit-specialization, fully-qualified-naming

In a recent discussion, the matter came up as to whether or not we should always fully qualify the **current** class' name in the class definition, and also use explicitly specialized templates when referring to the **current** template itself. To sum it up:

```
namespace foo {
    struct Foo {
        doSomething(foo::Foo& other); // arguably good
        doSomething(Foo& other);      // arguably bad
    };
}

template<typename T>
struct Bar {
    doSomething(Bar<T>& other); // arguably good
    doSomething(Bar& other);    // arguably bad
};
```

Problem is, no one could back up their claims with hard facts, it was merely "*the name lookup could go wrong*" versus "*meh, never had any problem*".

In order to settle this: **are those two conventions strictly equivalent or can the "bad" one sometimes introduce ambiguities in name lookup?** References to the current Standard would be very nice.

Of course, the argument of legibility should not be taken into account, I'm really asking about how a standard-conforming compiler will behave in corner cases. However, known implementation bugs are also welcome.

Comment: I don't think `foo::Foo` inside the namespace `foo` is "arguably good".

Comment: The 'arguably good' don't solve anything and could potentially introduce issues. There is nothing 'arguably bad' in the lines marked as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://ideone.com/f48mJI

```
namespace foo {
  namespace foo {
    typedef int Foo;
  }
  struct Foo {
    int m_foo;
    Foo( foo::Foo const& o_foo ):m_foo(o_foo.m_foo) {}
  };
}

int main() {
  ::foo::Foo foo_(::foo::foo::Foo{});
}
```

In conclusion, `Foo`.

Comment: Very good point, I didn't even think about being *this* devious. :)

Comment: I don't care if I get downvoted for a pointless comment, but I think `x` should be renamed to `foo`. Obviously for clarity. Also, it doesn't compile http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=653b0eb28a15e77dcdf6778eb4f94043-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: @willkill07 it not compiling is sort of the point.  What looks like a copy constructor is actually a constructor-from-`::foo::foo::Foo`, aka `int`: the syntax `foo::Foo` which attempts to be more exact, is actually "accidentally" pointing at the *wrong* type.... wait, that isn't right.  I mean: `foo`

Answer (score 1):

Certainly in the template case they're identical: The compiler injects something like `Bar = Bar<T>` into the class definition for you automatically.

Additionally for the first example I don't see any way that `Foo` could refer to anything other than the most locally nested `Foo`, in other words the current class.

Functionally speaking the two are equivalent but I'm going to argue that practically speaking they aren't: In each case, the more verbose one seems *harder* to grok and maintain.